# Jquery Modify Bootstrap data-dismiss

Tags: html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a HTML button that is using Bootstrap data-dismiss to close a form. I have a condition that is to prevent the user from proceeding if x field is not populated.

Once this button is pressed it goes to a diff form page and I have tried to access the button to no avail.

```
    <button  type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
```

I tried adding an id in and this did nothing.

```js
$("#close-edit-roles-save").click(function() {
  console.log('Hello world');
});

$(".btn btn-success").click(function() {
  console.log('Goodbye world');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id='close-edit-roles-save' type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
```

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. As it is it's very different from what is in the post. Don't stuff keywords into it. See [ask].

Comment: As you can see in the demo I added it works fine for the ID selector. Your class selector is faulty. It is looking for an element of type `btn-success` inside an element with class `btn`. That's not right for several reasons.

Comment: I will suggest that instead of messing with data attributes, just disable the button. That prevents events like modal dismiss from firing.